# PyQt5 support for signals in classes not inheriting from QObject

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qobject

in the "Differences Between PyQt4 and PyQt5" section (http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html), I can read the following line:

> Unlike PyQt4, PyQt5 supports the definition of properties, signals and slots in classes not sub-classed from QObject (i.e. in mixins).

However, in the "Support for Signals and Slots" section (http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html), I can read:

> New signals should only be defined in sub-classes of QObject. They must be part of the class definition and cannot be dynamically added as class attributes after the class has been defined.

Am I misunderstanding something or the 2 sentences contradict each other?

Comment: Second citation has right :)

Answer (score 2):

Note the *in mixins* part. It means you can do something like:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject

class SignalMixin:
    sig = pyqtSignal()

class Obj(SignalMixin, QObject):
    pass

o = Obj()
o.sig.connect(lambda: print('foo'))
o.sig.emit()
```